# How to copy table from one database to other database from assest folder in sqlite with an Android application

Tags: android, database, sqlite

I have two databases. I want to include database 1 of table in database 2. i check all question,but not meet any answer.so how it possible.

i have this two database which is show in image,i want add liked_product table of database 2 add in database 1.

database 1:

[image]

database 2:

[image]

Comment: `database 1 of table` ??? Where is database 1 ? Where is database 2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
private final String MY_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM table_a a INNER JOIN table_b b ON a.id=b.other_id WHERE b.property_id=?";

db.rawQuery(MY_QUERY, new String[]{String.valueOf(propertyId)});
```

Comment: have you any full tutorial.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html